# How does Bellman-Ford SSSP operate 'globally'?

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path, kruskals-algorithm, bellman-ford

In a programming class I took we learned the Bellman-Ford SSSP and Djikstra's SSSP, and we learned that Bellman-Ford was based off of Kruskal's minimal spanning tree algorithm, and that Djikstra's was based off of Prim's minimal spanning tree algorithm.

We were told to remember that Djikstra and Prim both operated on a local level, because you make your comparisons based off of edges and nodes that have already been selected, which makes sense to me. We were also told to remember that Bellman-Ford and Kruskal operated on a global level, because you select the smallest edge-weight, regardless of previously selected nodes.

For Kruskal's algorithm, I can understand why we can consider this to be global, because you literally just select the lightest or *smallest* edge weight. But for Bellman-Ford's algorithm, I just don't understand how it is considered to be global, because you do still need to worry about previously selected nodes and edges. How in the world is Bellman-Ford based off of Kruskal's algorithm, and how is it  considered to operate 'globally'?

Comment: `...you do still need to worry about previously selected nodes and edges` Do you? I seem to remember that you just repeatedly traversed all of them.

Answer (score 1):

It does seem fair to call Bellman-Ford global since it consists of many (|V|-1) relaxation passes, each of which involves iterating over all edges and updating distance estimates to (potentially) every other vertex.

I don't think there's any obvious conceptual connection between Kruskal and Bellman-Ford. In fact I think it is fair to say that Bellman-Ford is more similar to Dijkstra because of its use of iterative relaxation.